# accessing variable to another apps django

Tags: python, django

I have two apps in django

```
├── search
│   └── views.py
│       
└── preprocessing
    └── views.py
```

in search/views.py, i have dataframe with the code like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
def scrape(request):
    global df
    items = comments + replies
    df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Comments'])
    return render(request, 'search/scrape.html', context)
```

And, i want to use the dataframe from search/views.py in second apps

preprocessing/views.py

```
  from search.views import df

    def index(request):
        print(df)
        context = {
            
        }
        return render(request, 'preprocessing/preprocessing.html')
```

but the problem is dataframe that i pass to preprocessing/views.py is empty
so, how can i pass the datframe also with the value inside from search/views.py
thx for ur help

Comment: I would like to say, why do you use global variables? There is a reason people avoid using global variables. Particularly in a webserver (Django here) one would not want to use a global variable. Store data in the **database** or even files (although that might not be very optimal) **don't** use global variables.

Comment: If I don't use the database, is it still possible to access the variables df? @AbdulAzizBarkat

Comment: The problem is that when you write `df = pd.DataFrame(items, columns=['Comments'])` you create a new object and store it's reference in the variable `df`. The other module you have has imported `from search.views import df` and hence has a variable named `df` that has a reference to the old `df` object (when you make the new object it is not updated here because that would not make much sense, hence your variable `df` continues to have the old reference). Although I can think of a few ways to overcome this, I would suggest you to simply use the database instead of doing such things.